# devexpress textedit how to show date now

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, textedit

I'm using devexpress > textedit

What I'm trying to do is on load of the user control for textedit to show `now` date

here is the code I tried and it doesn't work:

```
Private Sub FeedbackAdmin_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If DateCreatedTextEdit Is Nothing Then
                DateCreatedTextEdit.EditValue = Now
            End If
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting an exception? Why don't use DateEdit instead of TextEdit?

Comment: I tried dateedit and it doesn't work either. no, i'm not getting any exceptions.

Comment: How exactly doesn't it work?

Comment: I want it to show todays date when I open usercontrol with this textedit/dateedit. I want it to be read only property and date should be populated automatically

Comment: I understand what you want. But, I don't understand what does not work.

Comment: it's not populating the date. textedit is blank when usercontrol is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is incorrect. You check if DateCreatedTextEdit is Nothing. You need to check if it's not Nothing.

```
If Not DateCreatedTextEdit Is Nothing Then
    DateCreatedTextEdit.EditValue = Now
End If
```

Comment: Works fine for me: http://screencast.com/t/mRLr1UCWBw. Handle the EditValueChanged event. Probably, EditValue is reset afterwards.